# Use an HTML <select> Element To Filter Taxonomies In WP Search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, forms

I have a WP search form where I would like to add a `<select>` element for a particular taxonomy and its terms (salary bands) for a custom post type of 'jobs'.

The current standard input search uses the following code to search the jobs custom post type for keywords:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url(site_url('/')); ?>">
    <div id="form-wrapper">
        <label id="searchlabel" for="s">Search</label>
        <input id="s" name="s" type="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="jobs" />
        <input class="td search-jobs-button" type="submit" value="Search Jobs">
    </div>
</form>
```

How would I add a `<select>` element that will show custom salary taxonomies in salary bands (e.g: £20-40k, £40 - 60k, £60-80k etc). The taxonomy terms will be added in the back end of the site obviously.

What I would like to happen is for people to be able to search keywords in the search input field and effectively filter these results by salary band using the select options.

Is there any way of adding each salary banding to an individual select option which is then included in the search when they click the submit input button?

Comment: You mean, a single-selection `<select>`?

Comment: hi @SallyCJ it would be a series of salary bands e.g. 20-40k, 40-60k, 60-80k, 80k+ (i'll amend the question to make that clearer)

Comment: So you're saying, you do want to allow users to select multiple options (i.e. one or more salary bands)? See the second and third examples [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdmk3ofw/). Also, is your taxonomy hierarchical?

Comment: @SallyCJ No, it will just be one salary band selected from the multiple options available. Yes it is hierarchical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a single-selection dropdown menu, then you can add the `<select>` element using [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/).

Here's an example with `salary_bands` being the taxonomy name/slug, and I'm placing the dropdown above or before the submit button, but you can just place it somewhere else in your form:

```php
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'        => 'salary_bands', // taxonomy slug
    'name'            => 'salary_bands', // taxonomy slug or query_var
    'value_field'     => 'slug',
    'selected'        => get_query_var( 'salary_bands' ),
    'hierarchical'    => true, // place each term under their own parent
    'show_option_all' => 'All Salary Bands',
) ); ?>
<input class="td search-jobs-button" type="submit" value="Search Jobs">
```

See the function reference for the full arguments list, but in the above, I set the `name` to the taxonomy slug (`salary_bands`) *and* the `value_field` to `slug` so that the `<option>` value will use the term slug (and not the default — the term ID).

And with those settings, we don't need to do the extra work of setting the selected terms via the `pre_get_posts` hook (or another hook), because WordPress would naturally automatically include the terms in the search query (its SQL statement).

**Notes:**

- *Make sure you use the correct taxonomy slug which is the first parameter for `register_taxonomy()` as in `register_taxonomy( 'salary_bands', ... )`*. Otherwise, you'd likely get an empty select menu!
- If you used a custom [`query_var` value](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#parameters), then set the above `name` value to the `query_var` value. And then use `get_query_var( 'query_var value' )`.

Additionally, you might want to use [`the_search_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_search_query/) like so:

```html
<input id="s" name="s" type="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
```

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ Thanks for this. The select element is showing, but the <option> elements that hold the terms is empty. I wondering if it's because of how I'm integrating it with the code in the original question? I can't seem to get it to work though.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? No label? No value? Can you include a screenshot and/or HTML for the `<select>` that you see in the page source? Did you change all the "salary_bands" to the correct taxonomy slug? And can you show your current form code?

Comment: hi @SallyCJ I've cut and pasted the code into this pen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/QWGQJXe?editors=1010 although I appreciate it won't render properly. The actual form has a little bit more to it than the original code such as SVG graphic etc. And the screenshot of what is happening is here: https://snipboard.io/Z4dqJ1.jpg (excuse the bad form styling).

Comment: Thanks. I could see you still using the `salary_bands` slug - is that actually the slug of your custom taxonomy as in `register_taxonomy( 'salary_bands', ... )` ?

Comment: Hi @TheChewy. I've just revised my answer - the code remained the same, but I reworded paragraphs 4 and onwards, and added extra details, specifically the "Notes" section.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I thought I had actually called the taxonomy 'salary_bands', but had actually named it 'salary_levels'. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: One final comment @SallyCJ - having applied this something else has occurred to me which I've posted under a new question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/384435/is-there-an-input-checkbox-option-that-works-like-wp-dropdown-categories-to , namely that people will most likely want to search under multiple job types / salary bands

Comment: I knew you'd change your mind about the single vs multi -selection :) But anyway, I've posted an answer there, so check it out and let me know! ( PS: Be sure the taxonomy slug is correct - because in your previous comment, you said it's `salary_levels`, but in the linked [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/384435/is-there-an-input-checkbox-option-that-works-like-wp-dropdown-categories-to), you actually used `salary_level` - no "s".. :) )